# Can't export query results to a csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, csv, export-to-csv

I've written the following code in an attempt to export the query result to a  csv file.

```
    def get_avg(self,f0, f00, f1, f2):
        arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13]
        for n in arr:
            curr_tab = c.execute("SELECT {}, {},  COUNT({}), AVG({}), AVG({}) FROM {} WHERE {} = {} GROUP BY {} ORDER BY COUNT({}) DESC".format(f0, f00, f00, f1, f2, self.table_name, f0, n, f00, f00)).fetchall()
            print(curr_tab)
        with open("cvc.csv", "w") as this_file:
            for i in curr_tab:
                csv.writer(this_file).writerow(i)
```

The problem is that when I press the button that calls this particular function, the file cvc.csv is created but nothing is written to the file.
while the result of print(curr_tab) on its own returns the desired results.

```
[(1.0, 'late', 1, 359.0, 11.0)]
[(2.0, 'early', 1, 460.0, 13.0)]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[(9.0, 'early', 1, 460.0, 19.0)]
[]
[]
[]
[]
```

Comment: You're only writing the result of the last query.

Answer (score 0):

Each time through the `for n in arr:` loop you replace `curr_tab` with the results of that query. So when you write to the CSV file, you're just writing the results of the last query.

You can either move the CSV writing inside that loop, or you can concatenate all the query results and write that.

```
def get_avg(self,f0, f00, f1, f2):
    arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13]
    all_tab = []
    for n in arr:
        curr_tab = c.execute("SELECT {}, {},  COUNT({}), AVG({}), AVG({}) FROM {} WHERE {} = {} GROUP BY {} ORDER BY COUNT({}) DESC".format(f0, f00, f00, f1, f2, self.table_name, f0, n, f00, f00)).fetchall()
        print(curr_tab)
        all_tab.extend(curr_tab)
    with open("cvc.csv", "w") as this_file:
        csv.writer(this_file).writerows(all_tab)
```